# Remove text in between anchors tags and also remove second <a> with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have SharePoint page which is generated. Now I am trying to remove text and second anchor tags from the below text.

Need to remove: Text is `or` (which is in between anchor tags) and remove second anchor or anchor text.

```
<table id="Hero-WPQ2" dir="none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td class="ms-list-addnew ms-textXLarge ms-list-addnew-aligntop ms-soften">
               <a id="idHomePageNewItem" class="ms-heroCommandLink" href="http://spfoundation/d" data-viewctr="5" onclick="NewItem2(event, &quot;http://spfoundation/d&quot;); return false;" target="_self" title="Add a new item to this list or library.">
               <span class="ms-list-addnew-imgSpan20">
               <img id="idHomePageNewItem-img" src="/dept/it/" class="ms-list-addnew-img20">
               </span>
                <span>new item</span>
                </a>

                 or 
                <a class="ms-heroCommandLink" href="javascript:;" onclick="EnsureScriptParams('inplview', 'InitGridFromView', '{23AB37B1-38E9-460B-BE87-FCAF204DAD20}'); return false;" title="Edit this list using Quick Edit mode.">edit</a>
                 this list
             </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
```

How can we do that with jquery? I tried with `$("td[class=ms-list-addnew*] a:nth-child(2)").text("");`. But did not worked.

### updated

Want to remove

```
or 
   <a class="ms-heroCommandLink" href="javascript:;" onclick="EnsureScriptParams('inplview', 'InitGridFromView', '{23AB37B1-38E9-460B-BE87-FCAF204DAD20}'); return false;" title="Edit this list using Quick Edit mode.">edit</a>
```

Comment: For jQuery you need to use `contents()` to access raw text nodes in a DOM element.

Comment: if i understood correctly you want to show only the anchor "new item", correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct @pumpkinzzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jQuery you need to use `contents()` to access raw text nodes in a DOM element. You can then check the nodeType to match text nodes (3 = text node: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp)

The index passed to `filter` lets you identify a specific element:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/53w8o35f/1/

```
$('td[class^="ms-list-addnew"]').contents().filter(function(i) {
        return this.nodeType === 3 && i == 2;     // Node.TEXT_NODE
   }).remove();
$('td[class^="ms-list-addnew"] a:last').remove();
```

*please adjust accordingly to remove any components in the HTML. This was just my best guess of what you wanted left.*

**Simpler option: (keep the bits you want)**

Another option is to simply match the things you want to keep and use `html(itemsIWantToKeep)` on the `td`. You can supply a function to `html()` so that the contents of each is applied to itself only.

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/53w8o35f/2/

```
$('td[class^="ms-list-addnew"]').html(function(){
    // Keep the first child of each td
    return $(this).children().first();    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

as was mentioned in the comments. You'll need to use `contents` to filter out the textNodes

http://jsfiddle.net/evilbuck/hh1598gk/

```
$('.ms-list-addnew a:nth-of-type(2)').remove();
$('.ms-list-addnew').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).eq(1).remove();
```

Comment: It removed "this list" text also. I want to show "new item this list"

Comment: nodeType == 1 is an element, not a text node. http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp

Comment: updated to reflect only one of the text nodes being removed. 1 is an element, it was specifying `!== 1`, but we can be more specific to just text nodes using the above.

Comment: Ah, missed the `!`, but generally you will want to target the text node specifically with `3`. It is actually cleaner to solve this by just retaining *the bits you want to keep*, but I am going to +1 yours anyway as it does work too :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
$('table td').html($('table td :first-child'))
```

Comment: Good idea, but you are applying the contents of *all* tds to *all* tds

Comment: then use the proper selector, like this: $('table td.ms-list-addnew-aligntop').html($('table td.ms-list-addnew-aligntop :first-child'))

Comment: Again that will not work for multiple TDs. Too many matches in the child expression. You wanted to use a function inside HTML to retain the current TD context. See my answer update for this.

Comment: Your answer would be even more useful if you elaborated why this is a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$($("td[class=ms-list-addnew*] a")[2]).prev().text("")
$($("td[class=ms-list-addnew*] a")[2]).text("")
```

Comment: You cannot access raw text nodes like that with jQuery. Suggest you test your own code in a JSFiddle?

Comment: $($("td[class=ms-list-addnew*] a")[2]).prev().remove()

Comment: Still incorrect for the question asked. Please re-read the question and try again :)